# Can I apply OLS (multiple regression) to panel data to identify significant variables?

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, least-squares, panel-data

I have panel data for a 5-year period and want to explore the determinants of car prices (number of doors, house power, etc.).

Is it appropriate to use OLS or multiple regression to explore the statistical significance of the independent variables? By using OLS, I assume there is a linear relationship between car characteristics and its price.

Comment: Car price is dependent variable (DV), and hourse power, number of doors, weight, and engine type are independent variables (IV). The cars have been observed each year. In addition, it's unbalanced panel because some cars are not sold anymore. I am interested not so much in estimating the effect of certain car characteristics on its price, but only to see if the relationship between DV and IVs is statistically significant. I have used OLS after examining scatterplots to see if there is linear relationship among variables.

Comment: Based an all cars in the sample, regardless of price, brand, etc. I want to be able to say, for example: characteristic X is statistically significant in determining car price. Like if I was having sample of people and see if weight would be statistical significant predictor of blodd pressure. I want to check the appropriatness of the methodology.

Comment: To get a qualified answer, you will need to provide details on the data structure. In general, the answer is "no" because in panel data, the standard errors that determine significances are not correct. You can easily see this by repeating each line in a regression data set four times: The standard errors of the estimated coefficients will be halfed but the information content is the same.

Comment: @Michael M what do you mean by "repeating each line in a regression data set four times"?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with using OLS to model panel data is that one is not accounting for fixed and random effects.

- Fixed Effects: Effects that are independent of random disturbances, e.g. observations independent of time.
- Random Effects: Effects that include random disturbances.

Firstly, you should use the Hausman test to determine whether fixed or random effects are present in your model. If you are using R, this can be done with phtest. More information can be found [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plm/versions/1.6-5/topics/phtest).

As an example, suppose we wish to determine the presence of fixed or random effects using the **gasoline** dataset in **plm**:

```
> library(plm)
Loading required package: Formula
> 
> data("Gasoline", package = "plm")
> form <- lgaspcar ~ lincomep + lrpmg + lcarpcap
> wi <- plm(form, data = Gasoline, model = "within")
> re <- plm(form, data = Gasoline, model = "random")
> phtest(wi, re)

    Hausman Test

data:  form
chisq = 302.8, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent
```

Given that the p-value is less than 0.05, this indicates that the null hypothesis of random effects is rejected - indicating that fixed effects are present in the model.

Two regressions are then run accounting for both fixed and random effects:

```
> summary(plmwithin)
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = form, data = Gasoline, model = "within")

Balanced Panel: n = 18, T = 19, N = 342

Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-0.378774 -0.039758  0.004650  0.045412  0.362856 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error  t-value  Pr(>|t|)
lincomep  0.662250   0.073386   9.0242 < 2.2e-16
lrpmg    -0.321702   0.044099  -7.2950 2.355e-12
lcarpcap -0.640483   0.029679 -21.5804 < 2.2e-16

lincomep ***
lrpmg    ***
lcarpcap ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    17.061
Residual Sum of Squares: 2.7365
R-Squared:      0.8396
Adj. R-Squared: 0.82961
F-statistic: 560.093 on 3 and 321 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
> summary(plmrandom)
Oneway (individual) effect Random Effect Model 
   (Swamy-Arora's transformation)

Call:
plm(formula = form, data = Gasoline, model = "random")

Balanced Panel: n = 18, T = 19, N = 342

Effects:
                   var  std.dev share
idiosyncratic 0.008525 0.092330 0.182
individual    0.038238 0.195545 0.818
theta: 0.8923

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu. 
-0.3977058 -0.0520350  0.0050877  0.0582288 
      Max. 
 0.3763726 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error  z-value
(Intercept)  1.996698   0.184326  10.8324
lincomep     0.554986   0.059128   9.3861
lrpmg       -0.420389   0.039978 -10.5155
lcarpcap    -0.606840   0.025515 -23.7836
             Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) < 2.2e-16 ***
lincomep    < 2.2e-16 ***
lrpmg       < 2.2e-16 ***
lcarpcap    < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    18.054
Residual Sum of Squares: 3.0817
R-Squared:      0.82931
Adj. R-Squared: 0.8278
Chisq: 1642.2 on 3 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

We can see that the fixed effects regression does not include the intercept, and the size of the coefficients have changed. Had a standard OLS model been run, then random effects may have been accounted for when the Hausman test is indicating that a fixed effects model better describes the relationships between these variables.

In this regard, an OLS regression is likely to be ineffective with panel data, as the differences between fixed and random effects are not being accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

You have just 5 year data. You need more data. Assume that we can use some methods on the given data to check for significance of effect of independent variables. We have an option to do so. Use OLS for ascertaining effect of individual Independent Variables on car prices. Further, you can utilize multiple regression to determine effect of a set of variables on car prices (DV). The results may differ because of different assumptions of two methods.